# "What days are the library open" vs. "What days is the library open"?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-number, be

I feel instinctively that the former is correct. However, the phrase "... are the library open" seems strange to me. What is the grammatical rule makes one of these correct over the other?

Comment: If you substitute the whole temporal expression 'On which days' (or use 'When') it becomes clear that the verb hass to agree with 'the library'. Or try 'On which days do John work?'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, it is reversed order.  The days are not open, the library is -- "library" is the (singular) subject.  The "normal" order would be "The library is open what days?"

Consider that you would use "are" in "What days are the city libraries open?"